# Ubuntu server blinking cursor

Tags: ubuntu, login, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 machine which recently stopped showing login prompt on the monitor.

The machine boots up properly, and we are able to work on it remotely, but can't login using the monitor/keyboard connected directly to the machine.

The packages are upgraded fairly regularly on the machine and didn't give off any errors.

I can't say when precisely the issue started as the machine is usually accessed remotely.

Comment: Press Alt+F2 on the console keyboard and note if anything happens.